# How to detect palindrome cycle length in a string?

Tags: string, algorithm, palindrome

Suppose a string is like this "abaabaabaabaaba", the palindrome cycle here is 3, because you can find the string aba at every 3rd position and you can augment the palindrome by concatenating any number of "aba"s to the string.

I think it's possible to detect this efficiently using Manacher's Algorithm but how?

Comment: Did you try googling before posting your homework assignment here? Don't see how you could be more clear than wikipedia for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring

Comment: @SébastienDawans that doesn't answer the question being asked. In the example given, the longest palindromic substring is "abaabaabaabaaba" - the entire string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it easily by searching the string S in S+S. The first index you find is the cycle number you want (may be the entire string). In python it would be something like:

```py
In [1]: s = "abaabaabaabaaba"

In [2]: print (s+s).index(s, 1)
3
```

The `1` is there to ignore the index `0`, that would be a trivial match.

Comment: This is really clever.  In the past, I've solved this problem by using the failure table from the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm.  It makes sense that it's also solvable this way.

Comment: @JohnKurlak In contests I also used to do that. Specially because you can modify the KMP to avoid materializing the string concatenation and work only with the original buffer. But this is an overkill for most applications, since almost all modern languages today implement a clever strfind (Java doesn't, which just confirms the rule).

Comment: I never knew that Java had a naive implementation.  Interesting!